# Как анимировать свойство эффекта?

Tags: c#, wpf, анимация, blur

```
DoubleAnimation animationblur = new DoubleAnimation {
    To = 100,
    Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
};
background.Effect.BeginAnimation(EffectProperty, animationblur);
```

Нужно плавно повысить у компонента background радиус блюра с 0 до 20, с помощью кода, то есть анимировать свойство radius в эффекте BlurEffect

Comment: Покажите имеющийся код и расскажите подробнее что хотите получить

Comment: А какого типа ваш `wallpaper.Effect`?

Comment: Отредактируйте исходный вопрос, нажмите [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/767923/edit) под текстом

Comment: @Laim0n пишите весь вопрос в вопросе, не надо его по частям в комментарии выкладывать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DoubleAnimation blurEffectAnimation = new DoubleAnimation
{
    From = 0,
    To = 10,
    Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.0)
};

Storyboard.SetTarget(blurEffectAnimation, background);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(blurEffectAnimation,
new PropertyPath("(Effect).Radius"));

Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();

sb.Children.Add(blurEffectAnimation);
sb.Begin();
```

Comment: это ответ на ваш вопрос?

Answer (score 0):

У меня была аналогичная проблема c радиусом у DropShadow. Вот решение:

```
private void Apple4_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    flyingObject = (FrameworkElement)sender;

    DoubleAnimation blur = new DoubleAnimation();
    blur.To = 200;
    blur.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.2);
    blur.AutoReverse = true;

    flyingObject.Effect.BeginAnimation(DropShadowEffect.BlurRadiusProperty, blur);
}
```

P.S. Предварительно на объекте уже должен быть эффект ... иначе будет ошибка.